# Can't get my bash prompts the way I want

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, prompt

I set `export PS1='[\u@\h \W](\#)\$ '` and source the setting file .profile. However, my prompt shows as

> \u@\h \W\$

I'm using bash on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your *.profile* is executed? According bash reference (/usr/share/doc/bash/bashref.pdf) operated with default settings bash will only read it when there is no *.bash_profile* and no *.bash_login* in your home directory (for interactive login shells) and only *.bashrc* for interactive **non-login** shells.

So it has to be called explicitly from the others if they exist and you want to use it.

Just to be sure, enter something like `echo "Hello .profile"` in *.profile*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set it in ~/.profile but in ~/.bash_profile
My ~/.bash_profile contains this:

```
# Debian prompt
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

If you edit it, make sure to "source" it after saving or you won't see the changes in your current terminal:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can also verify what PS1 is set to by running:

```
$ echo $PS1
```